# Pagination & Specification usage Spring Data

Tags: java, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my transactions

This below soltuion works perfectly fine

```
List<AccountTransactions> products = accountTransactionRepository.findAll(specification);

int skip = (page - 1) * ps;

List<AccountTransactionDto> transactionDtos =
        AccountTransactionMapper.toAccountTransactionDtoList(products).stream()
                .skip(skip).limit(ps).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But i got tried to do by using spring data as regarding suggestion in first post. Another reason is i think usign stream causes performance issues.

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface AccountTransactionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AccountTransactions, Integer>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<AccountTransactions> {
}
```

ServiceImpl. class

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(1, 5);

Page<List<AccountTransactions>> products = accountTransactionRepository.findAll(specification,pageable);
```

But this returns an error

```
Required type:
List
<AccountTransactions>
Provided:
Page
<AccountTransactions>
```

I think i need to return Page<List> as return type.

When i convert it to Page it works but returns the wrong result.

Also do you have any idea what is the best way as regarding the performance point of view?

Answer (score 1):

`findAll` by default returns Page instance. So you have to correct  following line:

**From**

```
Page<List<AccountTransactions>> products = accountTransactionRepository.findAll(specification,pageable);
```

**To**

```
Page<AccountTransactions> products = accountTransactionRepository.findAll(pageable);
```